# parallel instances of Robocopy not getting CPU time

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm trying to copy large directories from 3 sites. I noticed that robocopy was using < 25% of my CPU, I figured I can spawn 2 more instances in parallel to copy the other 2 sites.
However, I am finding that it seems that the first instance is getting all the CPU and the overall CPU usage is still at 25%. How can I get it to improve overall performance?

I am running with the following options:

```
Options : *.* /NS /NC /NDL /NFL /S /E /DCOPY:T /COPY:DT /PURGE /MIR /NP /XX /MT:4 /R:5 /W:30
```

Comment: [1] what does this have to do with powershell? [*grin*] [2] the `MT` option _defaults_ to `8`. you have set it to `4`. why? [3] the `MT` option is about _multi-threading_, not about multiple processes. if you want multiple _processes_ you will need to use something like the `start` command to fork off a new process OR something like the PoSh `*-Job` or `*-Process` cmdlets.

Comment: I call robocopy from powershell, just in case it matters. I set mt to 4 as I intend to run 3 instances of robocopy and was concerned about too many parallel io calls. I currently am running from 3 separate windows (eventually from 3 scheduled tasks)

Comment: thank you for the info about PoSh and the MT setting ... you likely otta add that AND the script you are using to make the calls to your Question. so, are you getting 25% cpu use with running 3 instances of RC? that seems wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar case, running 2 Robocopy instances. here is what I observed.

1. My Disk/Ethernet reach their capacity before CPU reaches its own one.
2. After adding /MT:32, it runs a lot faster than without this option. (default MT:8)

I also turned off anti-virus' file protection, otherwise it consumes more CPU but slows down the copy process.

[image]